# Agrupar valores de fim de semana e feriado para próximo dia útil

Tags: sql, postgresql

Galera, estou com com o seguinte problema, preciso agrupar todos os valores de saldo que caírem no sábado, domingo ou feriado para o próximo dia útil.

Tenho uma tabela **faturas** com os valores do `saldo` e o `vencimento`, e  **dim_feriados** com a `feriado_data` e a `feriado_descricao` (não importante).

Fiz essa consulta que aparentemente está funcional, porém acredito não estar da melhor forma pensando em performance.

```
SELECT
    vencimento_util
    , SUM(saldo) AS saldo
FROM    
(
    SELECT 
        vencimento AS vencimento_original
        , vencimento_data AS vencimento_nao_fds
        , CASE  
            WHEN EXTRACT ('ISODOW' FROM vencimento_data) = 5 AND feriado_data IS NOT NULL THEN vencimento_data + interval '3 days'
            WHEN EXTRACT ('ISODOW' FROM vencimento_data) <> 5 AND feriado_data IS NOT NULL THEN vencimento_data + interval '1 day'
            ELSE vencimento_data
        END AS vencimento_util
        , saldo
        , feriado_data
        FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            vencimento
            , EXTRACT('isodow' FROM vencimento) AS dia  
            , CASE WHEN 
                EXTRACT('isodow' FROM vencimento) > 5 THEN 1
                ELSE EXTRACT('isodow' FROM vencimento) 
            END AS dia_semana
            ,CASE 
                WHEN EXTRACT('isodow' FROM vencimento) < 6 THEN vencimento 
                WHEN EXTRACT('isodow' FROM vencimento) = 6 THEN vencimento + interval '2 days'
                WHEN EXTRACT('isodow' FROM vencimento) = 7 THEN vencimento + interval '1 day'       
            END AS vencimento_data
            , sum(saldo) AS saldo
        FROM faturas
        GROUP by vencimento
        ORDER by vencimento ASC
        ) t
        LEFT JOIN dim_feriados ON vencimento_data = feriado_data
    ) t2
GROUP BY vencimento_util
ORDER BY vencimento_util
```

Alguém poderia me auxliar a corrigir?

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/09b4d/7

Comment: O que você realmente precisa?

Comment: http://paposql.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/funcao-para-verificar-dia-util-no.html eu faria uma function para retoonar o enesimo dia útil.

Comment: @RORSCHACH preciso que os valores de sábado e domingo sejam agrupados com os da segunda (ou do próximo dia útil) e que os valores dos feriados sejam agrupados com os do próximo dia útil. Apenas saber uma forma melhor que a consulta que estou utilizando.

Comment: @Motta vou tentar verificar essa função e adaptá-la a minha necessidade! Valeu!